# Moving files from one folder to another on Dropbox mobile application

Tags: dropbox

How do I move the files (pictures and videos) from the camera uploads folder to a different folder in Dropbox that I have created?

Comment: This question is really difficult to answer without knowing the platform (Android, iOS, Windows Phone, Blackberry, Symbian, &c). A year has gone by with no answers because of this, and it can't really be answered without that, so might it be worth closing?

Comment: The OP wants to move pictures around in Dropbox. Apparently, there's a specific folder whereto the camera uploads.

Answer (score 1):

To move between Dropbox Folders on Android:

1. Open Dropbox
2. Tap source folder (e.g. "Camera uploads")
3. Long-tap desired file
4. Tap **Move**
5. Tap **Up to Dropbox**
6. Tap destination folder (e.g. "Public")
7. Tap **Move** (screen returns to source folder so scroll to top)
8. Select **Up to Dropbox** & destination folder (e.g. "Public")

You should see the file there.

Answer (score -1):

- Click the files to select them (keep the Ctrl (Cmd for Mac) button down to select multiple files (like in Windows/...).
- Then a `Move` option will appear at the top of the page.
- Hit that button and select the folder where you want the selected files to be moved to.

Comment: I did that but the folder I wanted to move the photo into said it was empty.

Comment: The OP asked for the *mobile* version.